# Tensorflow loading model issue with custom activation function

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, activation-function

I'm using a custom activation function but when I try to load model I get the error:

Exception encountered: Unknown activation function: 'function'. Please ensure you are using a `keras.utils.custom_object_scope` and that this object is included in the scope. See https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize#registering_the_custom_object for details.

I've checked some posts and followed some suggestions as below:

```
custom_objects = {"custom_fn": custom_fn}

with keras.saving.custom_object_scope(custom_objects):
   Model_2 = keras.models.load_model('agent2.h5',custom_objects={"custom_fn":custom_fn})
```

but the error is still there.

I am using tensorflow 2.13.0. I tried tensorflow 2.15.0 but it is the same.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Thank you,

Comment: See https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/serialization_and_saving?authuser=3#custom_objects, a bit further down under `Registering custom objects` is an example how you can serialize your function so that TF saves it too.

Comment: the problem is I saved as .h5 file. I changed to .keras file and it worked